# Can't debug an emulated Ionic app - minified code

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

Running this command...

```
ionic cordova emulate android
```

Problem is when debugging, all the code is minified (vendor.js and main.js) - hard to debug.

How do I get around this? I'd like to see both as my vendor.js is throwing an error. I'm sure there's an Ionic setting to stop this, but I checked the docs and did many searches, couldn't find anything.

Version is Ionic 3.

Ionic info contents...

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.1.2 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.0
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic 4.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.2, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.1.3, (and 16 other plugins)

System:

   NodeJS : v10.10.0 (/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.10.0/bin/node)
   npm    : 6.4.1
   OS     : macOS High Sierra
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Dos you try to search the file you wanna debug in the source tab in chrome devtools while you run ionic serve. It generally appears inside the src folder and then put the breakpoint or also you can put the word `debugger` in your code and it will stop your code there thats is how i do it.

Comment: Unfortunately sourcemaps are not available, so all I see is the minified code. Trying to debug that is not possible. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**
Run with the `--livereload` parameter.  I've found that using live reload provides sourcemaps when doing remote debugging more consistently than without live reload.

**Option 2:**
Add below to your package.json file.  That also works for me.  Not sure if this will impact prod builds or not, so you may want to only use this one when actively debugging.

```
"config": {
    "ionic_bundler": "webpack",
    "ionic_source_map_type": "#inline-source-map"
}
```

Comment: Yes, that does work, but I find the live reload to be pretty unstable - usually has issues for me communicating with the local dev machine. Hoping to get it working without live reload.

However , for the sake of anyone else who stumbles on to this question and has no issues with --livereload, this DOES work, Thanks BRass.

Comment: I added a non `--livereload` option that has worked for me too.